# How do I use the Blink_1Hz program in a clock program?

Tags: interrupt

I want to use the RPi Pico to build a clock.
In the documentation I found "blink_1hz.py" and I want to use the
1 second interrupt as counter for my clock.

The original program prints the system time every second correctly.
I only replaced the call to the lambda function in the irq by my own seconds counter function.

My problem is:
My version the of program  prints only once instead of ten times, and does not increment `t`.

I looked all over the internet but there is little specific information about the interrupts used by the StateMachines.
All suggestions are welcome

Here is my code:

```
# Example using PIO to blink an LED and raise an IRQ at 1Hz.
import time
from machine import Pin
import rp2

   
@rp2.asm_pio(set_init=rp2.PIO.OUT_LOW)
def blink_1hz():
    # Cycles: 1 + 1 + 6 + 32 * (30 + 1) = 1000
    irq(rel(0))
    set(pins, 1)
    set(x, 31) [5]
    label("delay_high")
    nop() [29]
    jmp(x_dec, "delay_high")

# Cycles: 1 + 7 + 32 * (30 + 1) = 1000
    set(pins, 0)
    set(x, 31) [6]
    label("delay_low")
    nop() [29]
    jmp(x_dec, "delay_low")

def secs():
    global t
    t = t+1
    print("secs",t)

t = 0

# Create the StateMachine with the blink_1hz program, outputting on Pin(25).
sm = rp2.StateMachine(0, blink_1hz, freq=2000, set_base=Pin(25))


# Set the IRQ handler to print the millisecond timestamp.

sm.irq(handler = secs()) # prints secs only once
#sm.irq(lambda p: print( time.ticks_ms())) # original, prints ticks every second

# Start the StateMachine.
sm.active(1)
time.sleep(10)
# Stop the StateMachine
sm.active(0)
print("main",t)
```

Comment: people, if you want answers, don't post [answers you don't think are right](/revisions/76155236/1), or abuse answers to ask for people to look at this. place [a bounty](/help/bounty) ([if you can](/help/privileges/set-bounties)), and follow the question (use the "follow" button) to get notifications about updates.

Comment: I definitely overlooked the follow button, thanks for the hint.  I am fairly certain that my answer is correct, but this is a topic fairly deep in the weeds that I am getting into.  I absolutely want to preface that I am not an expert on this topic, but I absolutely over-editorialized my response.  In a few months I'm going to be running this type of code in an experiment that I will be able to say for certain that I am correct and I hope to come back and provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my guess:

The handler needs to be passed a callable object (e.g. a function), but by passing `secs()` instead of `secs` you are passing a single instance (I'm foggy here about this part) of the called function instead of a callable object.  I know the pin based IRQ handlers also pass a parameter of the pin number, so perhaps the state machine IRQ will pass a reference to the state machine instance that threw the interrupt so your function definition might want to read `def secs(sm):` to capture that parameter even if you don't use it?